# Processing nested arrays

Tags: ruby

Given the following code (where I display some statistics about a number of bookings):

```
statistics = [["Germany", "EUR"], 23], [["Germany", "USD"], 42], [["Spain", "EUR"], 17]

statistics.each do |country_and_currency, number_of_bookings|
  country, currency = country_and_currency # <-- Ugly.

  puts "There are #{number_of_bookings} in #{currency} in #{country}"
end
```

The `country_and_currency` part is quite ugly. I tried `... do |*(country, currency), number_of_bookings|`, but this did not work.

Is there an elegant way to process this nested array without using the `country_and_currency` variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
statistics = [
               [["Germany", "EUR"], 23], 
               [["Germany", "USD"], 42], 
               [["Spain", "EUR"], 17]
             ]

statistics.each do |(country, currency), number_of_bookings|
  puts "There are #{number_of_bookings} in #{currency} in #{country}"
end
```

#### Output

```
There are 23 in EUR in Germany
There are 42 in USD in Germany
There are 17 in EUR in Spain
```

Answer (score 2):

```
statistics.each do |(country, currency), number_of_bookings|
  puts "There are #{number_of_bookings} in #{currency} in #{country}"
end
```